# How to remove/unsubscribe from service in core bluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I try to achieve it in the following way:

```
peripheral.services?.removeAll()
```

but it returns the error

> cannot use mutating member on immutable value

What is the correct way to remove or unsubscribe from service?

Comment: Is this a peripheral you are publishing via CBPeripheralManager or a peripheral you have discovered through a CBCentralManager?

Comment: I discovered this peripheral through a CBCentral, but peripheralManager removeAllServices() method did its job, maybe it happens because I write value to this peripheral using peripheralManager @Paulw11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error clearly state that `peripheral.services?` is not immutable content. so you cannot edit the contents in it.

You need to use

`removeAllServices()` - Removes all published services

and

`remove(CBMutableService)` - remove the specified service

`Apple` reference

[Core bluetooth  Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbperipheral)

Comment: I understand the error message, that's why I ask what is the correct way to do that? Also, you did not provide any answer, so why have you posted it as answer instead of comment?

Comment: This is deprecated, right? Can not find any option to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove services from a peripheral that is discovered using a `CBCentralManager`; the set of services that the peripheral has is set by that peripheral, which is why that property is immutable. The function you are trying to use is used when you are advertising a peripheral using `CBPeripheralManager`.

When you have connected to a peripheral, you can elect to receive notifications when a particular *characteristic* changes (if that characteristic supports `notify`) using `peripheral.setNotifyValue(bool, for: CBCharacteristic)` or you can disconnect from the peripheral entirely but you neither 'subscribe' nor 'unsubscribe' from a service.